# Change Style Shape Properties Visio PowerShell

Tags: powershell, visio

Does anyone know how to set the shape fill to transparent?

I tried the following code, but is not working.

```
$AppVisio = New-Object -ComObject Visio.Application
$AppVisio.Visible = $false 
$docsObj = $AppVisio.Documents
$DocObj = $docsObj.Add("Basic Diagram.vst")

$pagsObj = $AppVisio.ActiveDocument.Pages
$pagObj = $pagsObj.Item(1)

$Shape = $AppVisio.ActiveWindow.Page.DrawRectangle(0.315, 0.397, 3.315, 8.015)

$Shape.FillStyle = "Transparent"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With Visio, most of the properties that effect appearance, size and position are stored in the ShapeSheet.  So you need to find the right cell to address which, in this case, is `FillForegndTrans`.  So your line should read:

```
$Shape.CellsU('FillForegndTrans').FormulaU = '50%'
```

If you're not familiar with the ShapeSheet, you might find this useful background:

http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2007/10/just-for-starte.html